# How to set google charts image size

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm using `var imgUri = chart.getImageURI();` to get the image of the chart, but it's 400x200 and it kinda sucks, is there a way to increase it?

Comment: You may want to check & try the official Google Chart article on "Customize the Chart" at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_customizing_chart

Comment: thanks! that was what i was searching for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(thanks to [Irvin Jay G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15384825/irvin-jay-g) for the docs link)

I resolved by setting options as following:

```js
var options = {
    pointSize: 10,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    vAxis: {minValue: minValue}
};
```